# Is a Facebook JavaScript OAuth access token valid for Graph API?

Tags: facebook, oauth, feed, token

I've a question about access tokens. How many different access token exists?

Is the old OAuth still supported? Can I use the access token retrieved from OAuth JavaScript login for calling new [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)?

P.S. The Graph API feed shows me all my posts in the last 30 days(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is only one type of access token. Of course, I don't count "expired token", "invalid token", "application token", and "user token".

What I mean is: when the API expect an access token, you just need to get a valid one and make sure the necessary permissions are granted at that moment.

Comment: Ok, so access_tokens of old fb api (oauth) are still supported, right? They aren't different from oauth2's tokens?

Comment: Ok, fb need "stream_read" perms to do that... I solved my problem

Comment: there is nothing called "access_token for old fb api"... there is only one kind of token to me.

BTW, note that you have to migrated to OAuth 2.0 by 1Oct.